# Running service on android 9.0 or higher continuously

Tags: android, service, sms, backup

My app is about backing up `SMS/MMS` messages.

So far my idea was to back up `SMS/MMS` to an `XML` file instantly when they arrive or are sent,
then periodically upload created XML file to a cloud storage, even if app is not running.

This approach is the only one I found that is reliable enough for me to not lose any conversations.

Functions to do all that are mostly complete but I have noticed that google does not allow `service` to be `running continuously` on a device.

So, my question is, is there a way to make `service` run in `background` continuously without getting killed after a while. I am not interested in `foreground services` since i do not wish my users to have a `notification` displayed at all times.

This is my first app basically and I am not even sure if my approach to back-up software is correct.

I would love to have some input how should I tackle this problem. All I care at this moment is that my app will back-up every conversation instantly on `send` or `receive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission in your service
but you have to ask user for permission and also `android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission for "doze-mode" then use a `Thread` in the service for your `BroadCastReceiver`. this way guaranteed to make your service always running but it will cost battery life . i have tried and tested this for my app from api-level 19 to 28 and never stopped even in some devices like nokia with android `O` background running service disabled but with this trick you can keep it running. apps like Gameboosters or Cleaners also use this trick to keep there service alwyase running.

**UPDATE:**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <service
        android:name=".Service.NLService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Service

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = NLService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true)
                    try {
                        doSomeThing(NLService.this);
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        doSomeThing(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        doSomeThing(this);
    }
```

Request Permission

```
private static final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS = "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS";

public void askForNotificationServicePermission() {

        context.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));

}

public void askForDozeModePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            context.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

`doSomeThing(this);` is some method that you want to run for example your broudcastreceiver.

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide some code examples?

Comment: I have implemented your solution and tested it for 5-6h and serice is up and running for anyone else having same issues.